Deribit test API post requests failure
I am trying to hit this Deribit test API to place an order. I am facing error while sending POST requests using CURL.
I have generated the auth token. This also I did via GET as POST was not working.
// Function to place an order on Deribit
bool placeOrder(const std::string& access_token, const std::string& instrument_name, double amount) {
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (!curl) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to initialize curl" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    // failed: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "C:/Program Files/curl/cacert.pem");

    std::string order_url = "https://test.deribit.com/api/v2/private/buy";
    json payload = {
        {"instrument_name", instrument_name},
        {"amount", amount},
        {"price", "market"},
        {"label", "market0000234"}
    };
    std::string post_fields = payload.dump();
    std::string response;

    struct curl_slist* headers = nullptr;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, ("Authorization: Bearer " + access_token).c_str());
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, order_url.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, post_fields.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);

    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if (res != CURLE_OK) {
        std::cerr << "curl_easy_perform() failed: " << curl_easy_strerror(res) << std::endl;
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        return false;
    }

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    // Print the JSON response from the order
    std::cout << "Order response: " << response << std::endl;
    return true;
}

I am getting this as repsonse:
Order response: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"message":"bad_request","code":11050},"testnet":false,"usIn":1729933493033379,"usOut":1729933493033421,"usDiff":42}

Any idea why this is happening, or if I am doing something wrong.

First off, look at the error code here. It seems to mean they couldn't parse your request. I suggest you look at the raw json string you end up sending (after dump), see if it looks as expected. If there is no issue there, try sending the same request via curl CLI. If it works there, then you'll know it's an issue with your usage of libcurl. If it doesn't work there either, the issue is with your payload. Basically: you'll have to help yourself here by investigating.
